# How to write data to a text file in C# console application without overwriting the current data

Tags: c#, console-application

i need code in C# console application,saves the output data when application runs and that do not override previous data and saves continuously line by line

Comment: Hi, have you considered trying something on your own before asking for help? If so, show us where you-ve gotten to and we will help you understand where the problem is.

Comment: it's been good if you also post your code here, because without that we are not able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `StreamWriter` class overloaded constructor:
`using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(pathToFile, true))`,
second boolean parameter says if file should be appended (`true`) or overwritten (`false`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use File:

```
File.AppendAllText("test.txt", "mytext"+ Environment.NewLine);
```

If you have list of strings, You can do it in one line too.

```
 List<string> lists = new List<string> {"111","222","333" };
  File.AppendAllLines("test.txt",lists);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = 
            new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // If the line doesn't contain the word 'Second', write the line to the file.
                if (!line.Contains("Second"))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
```